# Server Implementation in java

Tags: sockets, client-server

I am implementing a server class. In this I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound  Exception when i am trying to pass hostName and portNumber as command line args.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EchoServer{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String hostName = args[0];
    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

if(args.length!=2){
System.err.println("Usage: java EchoClient <hostName> <portNumber>");
System.exit(1);

}



try(
    Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName,portNumber);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

) {
    String userInput; 
    while((userInput = stdIn.readLine())!=null){
        out.println(userInput);
        System.out.println("echo: " +in.readLine());
    }
}   catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
            System.exit(1);
     }  catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
            hostName);
         System.exit(1);
 }
}
```

}

Comment: swap first two lines of your `main` with next 4 lines

Comment: When i do that my code is only printing the error message.

Comment: @Hafix which means? that no arguments is passed, how do you call app?

Comment: i am passing hostname and portnumber as arg

Comment: How do you pass arguments?